# Getting error abour min validation in laravel

Tags: laravel

Good day

I am trying to update the info in database

this is my validation in api resource Controller

```
   if ($this->resourceModel()->getTable() == 'customers') {
        $request->validate([
            'birthday' => ['required'],
            'height' => ['min:3|numeric'],
            'weight' => ['min:2|numeric'],
        ]);
    }
```

on my TS file in angular , I input the height 100 and weight also is 100 to make sure that the validation will meet . However im getting error "The height must be at least 3|numeric characters." and "The weight must be at least 2|numeric characters."

I also tried to parse the string to check if it will fix the problem however im still getting the same error .

If i put four digits example : height - 1000 , weight - 1000
It will proceed , Why is that ? it says min is 3 for height and min for weight is 2 ,

Need help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   if ($this->resourceModel()->getTable() == 'customers') {
        $request->validate([
            'birthday' => ['required'],
            'height' => ['nullable|numeric|min:3'],
            'weight' => ['nullable|numeric|min:2'],
        ]);
    }
```

Change nullable to required as per requirements.. You can also use Grater than(gt)  validation rule e.g

> 'height' => ['required|numeric|gt:2']..

Comment: Both does not work for me . This is very weird ,I met the min condition but still getting error

Comment: Show the view file. from where you are sending request . and there is no need of large brackets 'birthday' => ['required'], => 'birthday' => 'required',

Comment: Have you tried Greater Than . ?

Comment: I figure out the problem , the numeric is the one causing the problem . But how do I convert the number if it is inside the object so the payload look like this height:"200"
weight:"200"
I already change the type of input from text to number , change the value in model from string to number and parseInt() but the payload is still the same

Answer (score 0):

You don't require the square brackets around your validation rules when you define them all in a single string, only when you define each rule individually.

```php
$request->validate([
    'birthday' => 'required',
    'height' => 'min:3|numeric',
    'weight' => 'min:2|numeric'
]);
```

Or

```php
$request->validate([
    'birthday' => ['required'],
    'height' => ['min:3', 'numeric'],
    'weight' => ['min:2', 'numeric'],
]);
```

**Update - 2022-04-08**

> the length of the digit ,base on the validation the min for height is 3 and for weight is 2 , but when i put height - 100 weight-50 , i got error . but when i put 4 digits each it works

Based on the above, you likely want to use either the [`digits`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-digits) or [`digits_between`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-digits-between) validation rule.

The former validates that a numeric value is **exactly** *n* digits, whilst the latter validates it is **between** *n* and *n+x*.

The issue with both of the above is that you can pass validation by providing all `0`s, so long as the number of `0`s you provide meets the value you specify for *n* in `digits:n` or `digits_between:n,n+x`.

So for example:

```php
'height' => 'digits:3'

'height' => 'digits_between:3,5'
```

If I provide the value of `height` as `000`, both of the above will pass validation. I assume this is not what you want. Therefore my recommendation is to use `min` and specify the minimum `height` and `weight` value you expect. As you have previously mentioned `3` digits for `height` and `2` digits for `weight`, I might assume the following:

```php
'height' => ['min:100', 'numeric']
'weight' => ['min:10', 'numeric']
```

The above will validate that the height must be at least `100` (3 digits) and the weight at least `10` (2 digits).

Comment: Works like magic T_T thank you so much @Peppermintology

Comment: But backend dev said dont change anything on API , any other way to do it just in angular ?

Comment: @aceGarcia Your backend dev said don't fix the broken code?

Comment: She said it was working on other api call . Changing it might mess up the app so i need to adjust on my front end

Comment: You have to fix it from backend ....

Comment: @SublanMustafa I tried to follow Peppermentology recommendation and it works , However , when I put less than the min . ex: height: 2 digits , weight: 1 digit , it did not get an error so that means the validation rule does not work .

Comment: @aceGarcia What do you want to validate, the number of digits, or the actual value?

Comment: the length of the digit ,base on the validation the min for height is 3 and for weight is 2 , 
but when i put height - 100 weight-50 , i got error . but when i put 4 digits each it works .

Comment: @aceGarcia Please see the update I have made to my answer.